# Create multiple HTML elements with a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

I currently have this: 
As you can see the two boxes are hard coded.

What is a the easiest way to create those 2 boxes with the given XML file?

```
<collection>
 <beanRepresentation>
 <beanRepId>222</beanRepId>
 <beanRepName>Bean 1</beanRepName>
 <top>0</top>
 <left>0</left>
 <height>0</height>
 <width>0</width>
 </beanRepresentation>

 <beanRepresentation>
 <beanRepId>223</beanRepId>
 <beanRepName>Bean 2</beanRepName>
 <top>0</top>
 <left>0</left>
 <height>0</height>
 <width>0</width>
</beanRepresentation>

</collection>
```

top is the "top" inside here, so is "left" and beanRepId is the "id":

```
<div class=" normal" id="1"
                        style="text-align:left;
                        top:  13em;
                        left: 5em;
                        height: 10em; 
                        width: 12em;">
```

I saw this example from http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table but document.write does not work, the boxes do not get drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a working example [here](http://cdn.florianbussmann.de/stackoverflow/21140602.html). Note that i modified the XML file. The script looks as following

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("beanRepresentation");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 
    document.write("<div class=\"normal\" id=\"");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("beanRepId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("\" style=\"text-align:left;\ top:");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("top")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("em; left:");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("left")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("em; height:");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("height")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("em; width:");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("width")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("em;\"></div>");
}
```

It is based on the [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table) you linked to. Feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: So I assume the modification you  made to the XML is the positions? So they dont stack on top of each other? And also the height and width of the boxes right?

Comment: You are right. I just wanted to make sure the script gets the correct values, unfortunately those values you mentioned are set to 0 in your XML example. However you may take a look at the XML file [here](http://cdn.florianbussmann.de/stackoverflow/21140602_catalog.xml).

Comment: Ok thanks. Another question is I dont know if I am retrieving the xml file in the first place. For testing purposes I used: xmlhttp.open("GET","http://cdn.florianbussmann.de/stackoverflow/21140602_catalog.xml",false); Is this supposed to work?

Comment: Works for me. I made a „ready to use“ archive which you can download [here](http://cdn.florianbussmann.de/stackoverflow/21140602.zip). Note that it won't work on your local drive because XMLHttpRequests, cross origin requests, are only supported for HTTP.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. the URL field should just be the URL that links to the .XML file right

Comment: One more thing, I also want to make each box draggable by adding this line : jsPlumb.draggable(id);  in the .js. Can I do the same thing I did here? Using Document.write() in my .js file? @florianbussmann

Comment: The function document.write() is not needed here. Just add jsPlumb.draggable(x[i].getElementsByTagName("beanRepId")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); after the output generated by document.write(...). Also updated the example.

Comment: For some reason, jsPlumb.draggable() does not work in the .html file inside the <script></script> where all this code is at right now

Comment: Have you added a reference to jQuery and jsPlumb at the top of your document? I updated the [„ready to use“ archive](http://cdn.florianbussmann.de/stackoverflow/21140602.zip) for you.

Comment: Ah ok that was the problem, didnt add the src header, thank you very much. Works fine now!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45317/discussion-between-jenny-and-florianbussmann)

Comment: you better avoid `document.write`